# Need help making this inline form aligned to the center

Tags: html, css, inline-formset, activecampaign

I tried editing this form on Active Campaign with codes I found online. I am having 2 problems:

1. On the mobile version, the first box is not centered. [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phzc1.png)
2. On the desktop version, the submit button is also misaligned. [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5K9f.png)

Is there a way to fix these 2 problems?

```html
<style>
& {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  outline: 0;
}
GLOBAL-STYLE ._form_hide {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
GLOBAL-STYLE ._form_show {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
._form-top {
  top: 0;
}
._form-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
._form-left {
  left: 0;
}
._form-right {
  right: 0;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
textarea {
  padding: 6px;
  height: auto;
  border: #979797 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
._submit {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E9AFA3 !important;border: 0 !important;color: #FFFFFF !important;padding:12px !important}
._close-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url('https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/esfkyjh1u_forms-close-dark.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 14.2px 14.2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 11px;
  right: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 16.2px;
  height: 16.2px;
}
._close-icon:before {
  position: relative;
}
._form-body {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
._form-image-left {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
._form-content-right {
  margin-left: 164px;
}
._form-branding {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
._form-branding ._logo {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background-image: url('https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/hh9ujqgv5_aclogo_li.png');
  background-size: 130px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.form-sr-only{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
._form-label,
._form_element ._form-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}
._dark ._form-branding {
  color: #333;
}
._dark ._form-branding ._logo {
  background-image: url('https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/jftq2c8s_aclogo_dk.png');
}
._form_element {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
._form_element * {
  font-size: 14px;
}
._form_element._clear {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
._form_element._clear:after {
  clear: left;
}
._form_element input[type="text"],
._form_element input[type="date"],
._form_element select,
._form_element textarea:not(.g-recaptcha-response) {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
}
._field-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
._inline-style {
  float: left;
}
._inline-style input[type="text"] {
  width: 150px;
}
._inline-style:not(._clear) + ._inline-style:not(._clear) {
  margin-left: 20px;
  }
._form_element img._form-image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
._form_element ._form-fieldset{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.01em 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

._clear-element {
  clear: left;
}
._full_width {
  width: 100%;
}
._form_full_field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="text"]._has_error,
textarea._has_error {
  border: #F37C7B 1px solid;
}
input[type="checkbox"]._has_error {
  outline: #F37C7B 1px solid;
}
._error {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 10000001;
}
._error._above {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  bottom: 39px;
  right: 0;
}
._error._below {
  padding-top: 4px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
._error._above ._error-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #F37C7B;
}
._error._below ._error-arrow {
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #F37C7B;
}
._error-inner {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: #F37C7B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
._error-inner._form_error {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
._button-wrapper ._error-inner._form_error {
  position: static;
}
._error-inner._no_arrow {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
._error-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
._error-html {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
GLOBAL-STYLE .pika-single {
  z-index: 10000001 !important;
}
input[type="text"].datetime_date {
  width: 69%;
  display: inline;
}
select.datetime_time {
  width: 29%;
  display: inline;
  height: 32px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 667px) {
  GLOBAL-STYLE ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  & {
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  ._form-content {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ._form-inner {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  ._form-title,
  ._inline-style {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  ._form-title {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  ._form_element {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
  }
  ._form-element,
  ._inline-style,
  input[type="text"],
  label,
  p,
  textarea:not(.g-recaptcha-response) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ._row._checkbox-radio label {
    display: inline;
  }
  ._row,
  p,
  label {
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ._row input[type="checkbox"],
  ._row input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
  ._row input[type="checkbox"] + span label {
    display: inline;
  }
  ._row span label {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: initial !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
  ._form-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"],
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 0.3em 0 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  button[type="submit"] {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  ._inline-style {
    margin: 20px 0 0 !important;
  }
}
& {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  *zoom: 1;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 2px solid ##f9d2cb !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  color: #787878 !important;
}
    ._inline-form,
  ._inline-form ._form-content,
  ._inline-form input,
  ._inline-form ._submit{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif, 'IBM Plex Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  }

._form-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
&:before,
&:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
&:after {
  clear: both;
}
._inline-style {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
._inline-style input[type="text"],
._inline-style input[type="date"] {
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
._inline-style button._inline-style {
  position: relative;
  top: 27px;
}
._inline-style p {
  margin: 0;
}
._inline-style ._button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 27px 12.5px 0 20px;
}
._form-thank-you {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 667px) {
  ._inline-form._inline-style ._inline-style._button-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
 #_form_1_ ._submit { width:222px; }
 #_form_1_ ._x35027614 input { border-radius:0px; width:222px; border-color:#e9afa3; }
 #_form_1_ ._x49576109 input { border-radius:0px; width:222px; border-color:#e9afa3; }
 #_form_1_ ._x43479952 input { border-radius:0px; width:222px; border-color:#e9afa3; }
</style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&amp;family=Montserrat&amp;family=Roboto&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <form method="POST" action="https://bonniebrightdesigns.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_1_" class="_form _form_1 _inline-form _inline-style _dark" novalidate="">
      <input type="hidden" name="u" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="f" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="s">
      <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="act" value="sub">
      <input type="hidden" name="v" value="2">
      <div class="_form-content">
        <div class="_form_element _x35027614 _inline-style ">
          <label for="firstname" class="_form-label">
            &nbsp;
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_form_element _x49576109 _inline-style ">
          <label for="lastname" class="_form-label">
            &nbsp;
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_form_element _x43479952 _inline-style ">
          <label for="email" class="_form-label">
            &nbsp;
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_button-wrapper _inline-style">
          <button id="_form_1_submit" class="_submit" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="_clear-element">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_form-thank-you" style="display:none;">
      </div>
      <div class="_form-branding">
        <div class="_marketing-by">
          Marketing by
        </div>
        <a href="https://www.activecampaign.com/?utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=acforms" class="_logo">
          <span class="form-sr-only">
            ActiveCampaign
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div><script type="text/javascript">
window.cfields = [];
window._show_thank_you = function(id, message, trackcmp_url, email) {
  var form = document.getElementById('_form_' + id + '_'), thank_you = form.querySelector('._form-thank-you');
  form.querySelector('._form-content').style.display = 'none';
  thank_you.innerHTML = message;
  thank_you.style.display = 'block';
  const vgoAlias = typeof visitorGlobalObjectAlias === 'undefined' ? 'vgo' : visitorGlobalObjectAlias;
  var visitorObject = window[vgoAlias];
  if (email && typeof visitorObject !== 'undefined') {
    visitorObject('setEmail', email);
    visitorObject('update');
  } else if (typeof(trackcmp_url) != 'undefined' && trackcmp_url) {
    // Site tracking URL to use after inline form submission.
    _load_script(trackcmp_url);
  }
  if (typeof window._form_callback !== 'undefined') window._form_callback(id);
};
window._show_error = function(id, message, html) {
  var form = document.getElementById('_form_' + id + '_'), err = document.createElement('div'), button = form.querySelector('button'), old_error = form.querySelector('._form_error');
  if (old_error) old_error.parentNode.removeChild(old_error);
  err.innerHTML = message;
  err.className = '_error-inner _form_error _no_arrow';
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = '_form-inner';
  wrapper.appendChild(err);
  button.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, button);
  document.querySelector('[id^="_form"][id$="_submit"]').disabled = false;
  if (html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = '_error-html';
    div.innerHTML = html;
    err.appendChild(div);
  }
};
window._load_script = function(url, callback) {
  var head = document.querySelector('head'), script = document.createElement('script'), r = false;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.charset = 'utf-8';
  script.src = url;
  if (callback) {
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (!r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
        r = true;
        callback();
      }
    };
  }
  head.appendChild(script);
};
(function() {
  if (window.location.search.search("excludeform") !== -1) return false;
  var getCookie = function(name) {
    var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^|; )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
    return match ? match[2] : null;
  }
  var setCookie = function(name, value) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var expireTime = time + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
    now.setTime(expireTime);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + now + ';path=/';
  }
      var addEvent = function(element, event, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(event, func);
    } else {
      var oldFunc = element['on' + event];
      element['on' + event] = function() {
        oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
        func.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    }
  }
  var _removed = false;
  var form_to_submit = document.getElementById('_form_1_');
  var allInputs = form_to_submit.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'), tooltips = [], submitted = false;

  var getUrlParam = function(name) {
    var regexStr = '[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)';
    var results = new RegExp(regexStr, 'i').exec(window.location.href);
    return results != undefined ? decodeURIComponent(results[1]) : false;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    var regexStr = "field\\[(\\d+)\\]";
    var results = new RegExp(regexStr).exec(allInputs[i].name);
    if (results != undefined) {
      allInputs[i].dataset.name = window.cfields[results[1]];
    } else {
      allInputs[i].dataset.name = allInputs[i].name;
    }
    var fieldVal = getUrlParam(allInputs[i].dataset.name);

    if (fieldVal) {
      if (allInputs[i].dataset.autofill === "false") {
        continue;
      }
      if (allInputs[i].type == "radio" || allInputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        if (allInputs[i].value == fieldVal) {
          allInputs[i].checked = true;
        }
      } else {
        allInputs[i].value = fieldVal;
      }
    }
  }

  var remove_tooltips = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
      tooltips[i].tip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltips[i].tip);
    }
    tooltips = [];
  };
  var remove_tooltip = function(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
      if (tooltips[i].elem === elem) {
        tooltips[i].tip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltips[i].tip);
        tooltips.splice(i, 1);
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  var create_tooltip = function(elem, text) {
    var tooltip = document.createElement('div'), arrow = document.createElement('div'), inner = document.createElement('div'), new_tooltip = {};
    if (elem.type != 'radio' && elem.type != 'checkbox') {
      tooltip.className = '_error';
      arrow.className = '_error-arrow';
      inner.className = '_error-inner';
      inner.innerHTML = text;
      tooltip.appendChild(arrow);
      tooltip.appendChild(inner);
      elem.parentNode.appendChild(tooltip);
    } else {
      tooltip.className = '_error-inner _no_arrow';
      tooltip.innerHTML = text;
      elem.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, elem);
      new_tooltip.no_arrow = true;
    }
    new_tooltip.tip = tooltip;
    new_tooltip.elem = elem;
    tooltips.push(new_tooltip);
    return new_tooltip;
  };
  var resize_tooltip = function(tooltip) {
    var rect = tooltip.elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var doc = document.documentElement, scrollPosition = rect.top - ((window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0));
    if (scrollPosition < 40) {
      tooltip.tip.className = tooltip.tip.className.replace(/ ?(_above|_below) ?/g, '') + ' _below';
    } else {
      tooltip.tip.className = tooltip.tip.className.replace(/ ?(_above|_below) ?/g, '') + ' _above';
    }
  };
  var resize_tooltips = function() {
    if (_removed) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
      if (!tooltips[i].no_arrow) resize_tooltip(tooltips[i]);
    }
  };
  var validate_field = function(elem, remove) {
    var tooltip = null, value = elem.value, no_error = true;
    remove ? remove_tooltip(elem) : false;
    if (elem.type != 'checkbox') elem.className = elem.className.replace(/ ?_has_error ?/g, '');
    if (elem.getAttribute('required') !== null) {
      if (elem.type == 'radio' || (elem.type == 'checkbox' && /any/.test(elem.className))) {
        var elems = form_to_submit.elements[elem.name];
        if (!(elems instanceof NodeList || elems instanceof HTMLCollection) || elems.length <= 1) {
          no_error = elem.checked;
        }
        else {
          no_error = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].checked) no_error = true;
          }
        }
        if (!no_error) {
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Please select an option.");
        }
      } else if (elem.type =='checkbox') {
        var elems = form_to_submit.elements[elem.name], found = false, err = [];
        no_error = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          if (elems[i].getAttribute('required') === null) continue;
          if (!found && elems[i] !== elem) return true;
          found = true;
          elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace(/ ?_has_error ?/g, '');
          if (!elems[i].checked) {
            no_error = false;
            elems[i].className = elems[i].className + ' _has_error';
            err.push("Checking %s is required".replace("%s", elems[i].value));
          }
        }
        if (!no_error) {
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, err.join('<br/>'));
        }
      } else if (elem.tagName == 'SELECT') {
        var selected = true;
        if (elem.multiple) {
          selected = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
            if (elem.options[i].selected) {
              selected = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
            if (elem.options[i].selected && !elem.options[i].value) {
              selected = false;
            }
          }
        }
        if (!selected) {
          elem.className = elem.className + ' _has_error';
          no_error = false;
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Please select an option.");
        }
      } else if (value === undefined || value === null || value === '') {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' _has_error';
        no_error = false;
        tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "This field is required.");
      }
    }
    if (no_error && elem.name == 'email') {
      if (!value.match(/^[\+_a-z0-9-'&=]+(\.[\+_a-z0-9-']+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' _has_error';
        no_error = false;
        tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Enter a valid email address.");
      }
    }
    if (no_error && /date_field/.test(elem.className)) {
      if (!value.match(/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' _has_error';
        no_error = false;
        tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Enter a valid date.");
      }
    }
    tooltip ? resize_tooltip(tooltip) : false;
    return no_error;
  };
  var needs_validate = function(el) {
        if(el.getAttribute('required') !== null){
            return true
        }
        if(el.name === 'email' && el.value !== ""){
            return true
        }
        return false
  };
  var validate_form = function(e) {
    var err = form_to_submit.querySelector('._form_error'), no_error = true;
    if (!submitted) {
      submitted = true;
      for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var input = allInputs[i];
        if (needs_validate(input)) {
          if (input.type == 'text') {
            addEvent(input, 'blur', function() {
              this.value = this.value.trim();
              validate_field(this, true);
            });
            addEvent(input, 'input', function() {
              validate_field(this, true);
            });
          } else if (input.type == 'radio' || input.type == 'checkbox') {
            (function(el) {
              var radios = form_to_submit.elements[el.name];
              for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
                addEvent(radios[i], 'click', function() {
                  validate_field(el, true);
                });
              }
            })(input);
          } else if (input.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            addEvent(input, 'change', function() {
              validate_field(this, true);
            });
          } else if (input.type == 'textarea'){
            addEvent(input, 'input', function() {
              validate_field(this, true);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
    remove_tooltips();
    for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
      var elem = allInputs[i];
      if (needs_validate(elem)) {
        if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "select") {
          elem.value = elem.value.trim();
        }
        validate_field(elem) ? true : no_error = false;
      }
    }
    if (!no_error && e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    resize_tooltips();
    return no_error;
  };
  addEvent(window, 'resize', resize_tooltips);
  addEvent(window, 'scroll', resize_tooltips);
  window._old_serialize = null;
  if (typeof serialize !== 'undefined') window._old_serialize = window.serialize;
  _load_script("//d3rxaij56vjege.cloudfront.net/form-serialize/0.3/serialize.min.js", function() {
    window._form_serialize = window.serialize;
    if (window._old_serialize) window.serialize = window._old_serialize;
  });
  var form_submit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate_form()) {
      // use this trick to get the submit button & disable it using plain javascript
      document.querySelector('#_form_1_submit').disabled = true;
            var serialized = _form_serialize(document.getElementById('_form_1_')).replace(/%0A/g, '\\n');
      var err = form_to_submit.querySelector('._form_error');
      err ? err.parentNode.removeChild(err) : false;
      _load_script('https://bonniebrightdesigns.activehosted.com/proc.php?' + serialized + '&jsonp=true');
    }
    return false;
  };
  addEvent(form_to_submit, 'submit', form_submit);
})();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code was quite messy but  I did my best.

```js
window.cfields = [];
  window._show_thank_you = function (id, message, trackcmp_url, email) {
    var form = document.getElementById("_form_" + id + "_"),
      thank_you = form.querySelector("._form-thank-you");
    form.querySelector("._form-content").style.display = "none";
    thank_you.innerHTML = message;
    thank_you.style.display = "block";
    const vgoAlias =
      typeof visitorGlobalObjectAlias === "undefined"
        ? "vgo"
        : visitorGlobalObjectAlias;
    var visitorObject = window[vgoAlias];
    if (email && typeof visitorObject !== "undefined") {
      visitorObject("setEmail", email);
      visitorObject("update");
    } else if (typeof trackcmp_url != "undefined" && trackcmp_url) {
      // Site tracking URL to use after inline form submission.
      _load_script(trackcmp_url);
    }
    if (typeof window._form_callback !== "undefined") window._form_callback(id);
  };
  window._show_error = function (id, message, html) {
    var form = document.getElementById("_form_" + id + "_"),
      err = document.createElement("div"),
      button = form.querySelector("button"),
      old_error = form.querySelector("._form_error");
    if (old_error) old_error.parentNode.removeChild(old_error);
    err.innerHTML = message;
    err.className = "_error-inner _form_error _no_arrow";
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.className = "_form-inner";
    wrapper.appendChild(err);
    button.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, button);
    document.querySelector('[id^="_form"][id$="_submit"]').disabled = false;
    if (html) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "_error-html";
      div.innerHTML = html;
      err.appendChild(div);
    }
  };
  window._load_script = function (url, callback) {
    var head = document.querySelector("head"),
      script = document.createElement("script"),
      r = false;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.charset = "utf-8";
    script.src = url;
    if (callback) {
      script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "complete")) {
          r = true;
          callback();
        }
      };
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
  };
  (function () {
    if (window.location.search.search("excludeform") !== -1) return false;
    var getCookie = function (name) {
      var match = document.cookie.match(
        new RegExp("(^|; )" + name + "=([^;]+)")
      );
      return match ? match[2] : null;
    };
    var setCookie = function (name, value) {
      var now = new Date();
      var time = now.getTime();
      var expireTime = time + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
      now.setTime(expireTime);
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + now + ";path=/";
    };
    var addEvent = function (element, event, func) {
      if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, func);
      } else {
        var oldFunc = element["on" + event];
        element["on" + event] = function () {
          oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
          func.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      }
    };
    var _removed = false;
    var form_to_submit = document.getElementById("_form_1_");
    var allInputs = form_to_submit.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea"),
      tooltips = [],
      submitted = false;

    var getUrlParam = function (name) {
      var regexStr = "[\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
      var results = new RegExp(regexStr, "i").exec(window.location.href);
      return results != undefined ? decodeURIComponent(results[1]) : false;
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
      var regexStr = "field\\[(\\d+)\\]";
      var results = new RegExp(regexStr).exec(allInputs[i].name);
      if (results != undefined) {
        allInputs[i].dataset.name = window.cfields[results[1]];
      } else {
        allInputs[i].dataset.name = allInputs[i].name;
      }
      var fieldVal = getUrlParam(allInputs[i].dataset.name);

      if (fieldVal) {
        if (allInputs[i].dataset.autofill === "false") {
          continue;
        }
        if (allInputs[i].type == "radio" || allInputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
          if (allInputs[i].value == fieldVal) {
            allInputs[i].checked = true;
          }
        } else {
          allInputs[i].value = fieldVal;
        }
      }
    }

    var remove_tooltips = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].tip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltips[i].tip);
      }
      tooltips = [];
    };
    var remove_tooltip = function (elem) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        if (tooltips[i].elem === elem) {
          tooltips[i].tip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltips[i].tip);
          tooltips.splice(i, 1);
          return;
        }
      }
    };
    var create_tooltip = function (elem, text) {
      var tooltip = document.createElement("div"),
        arrow = document.createElement("div"),
        inner = document.createElement("div"),
        new_tooltip = {};
      if (elem.type != "radio" && elem.type != "checkbox") {
        tooltip.className = "_error";
        arrow.className = "_error-arrow";
        inner.className = "_error-inner";
        inner.innerHTML = text;
        tooltip.appendChild(arrow);
        tooltip.appendChild(inner);
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(tooltip);
      } else {
        tooltip.className = "_error-inner _no_arrow";
        tooltip.innerHTML = text;
        elem.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, elem);
        new_tooltip.no_arrow = true;
      }
      new_tooltip.tip = tooltip;
      new_tooltip.elem = elem;
      tooltips.push(new_tooltip);
      return new_tooltip;
    };
    var resize_tooltip = function (tooltip) {
      var rect = tooltip.elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      var doc = document.documentElement,
        scrollPosition =
          rect.top -
          ((window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0));
      if (scrollPosition < 40) {
        tooltip.tip.className =
          tooltip.tip.className.replace(/ ?(_above|_below) ?/g, "") + " _below";
      } else {
        tooltip.tip.className =
          tooltip.tip.className.replace(/ ?(_above|_below) ?/g, "") + " _above";
      }
    };
    var resize_tooltips = function () {
      if (_removed) return;
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        if (!tooltips[i].no_arrow) resize_tooltip(tooltips[i]);
      }
    };
    var validate_field = function (elem, remove) {
      var tooltip = null,
        value = elem.value,
        no_error = true;
      remove ? remove_tooltip(elem) : false;
      if (elem.type != "checkbox")
        elem.className = elem.className.replace(/ ?_has_error ?/g, "");
      if (elem.getAttribute("required") !== null) {
        if (
          elem.type == "radio" ||
          (elem.type == "checkbox" && /any/.test(elem.className))
        ) {
          var elems = form_to_submit.elements[elem.name];
          if (
            !(elems instanceof NodeList || elems instanceof HTMLCollection) ||
            elems.length <= 1
          ) {
            no_error = elem.checked;
          } else {
            no_error = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
              if (elems[i].checked) no_error = true;
            }
          }
          if (!no_error) {
            tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Please select an option.");
          }
        } else if (elem.type == "checkbox") {
          var elems = form_to_submit.elements[elem.name],
            found = false,
            err = [];
          no_error = true;
          for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].getAttribute("required") === null) continue;
            if (!found && elems[i] !== elem) return true;
            found = true;
            elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace(
              / ?_has_error ?/g,
              ""
            );
            if (!elems[i].checked) {
              no_error = false;
              elems[i].className = elems[i].className + " _has_error";
              err.push("Checking %s is required".replace("%s", elems[i].value));
            }
          }
          if (!no_error) {
            tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, err.join("<br/>"));
          }
        } else if (elem.tagName == "SELECT") {
          var selected = true;
          if (elem.multiple) {
            selected = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
              if (elem.options[i].selected) {
                selected = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
              if (elem.options[i].selected && !elem.options[i].value) {
                selected = false;
              }
            }
          }
          if (!selected) {
            elem.className = elem.className + " _has_error";
            no_error = false;
            tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Please select an option.");
          }
        } else if (value === undefined || value === null || value === "") {
          elem.className = elem.className + " _has_error";
          no_error = false;
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "This field is required.");
        }
      }
      if (no_error && elem.name == "email") {
        if (
          !value.match(
            /^[\+_a-z0-9-'&=]+(\.[\+_a-z0-9-']+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i
          )
        ) {
          elem.className = elem.className + " _has_error";
          no_error = false;
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Enter a valid email address.");
        }
      }
      if (no_error && /date_field/.test(elem.className)) {
        if (!value.match(/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/)) {
          elem.className = elem.className + " _has_error";
          no_error = false;
          tooltip = create_tooltip(elem, "Enter a valid date.");
        }
      }
      tooltip ? resize_tooltip(tooltip) : false;
      return no_error;
    };
    var needs_validate = function (el) {
      if (el.getAttribute("required") !== null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (el.name === "email" && el.value !== "") {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    var validate_form = function (e) {
      var err = form_to_submit.querySelector("._form_error"),
        no_error = true;
      if (!submitted) {
        submitted = true;
        for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
          var input = allInputs[i];
          if (needs_validate(input)) {
            if (input.type == "text") {
              addEvent(input, "blur", function () {
                this.value = this.value.trim();
                validate_field(this, true);
              });
              addEvent(input, "input", function () {
                validate_field(this, true);
              });
            } else if (input.type == "radio" || input.type == "checkbox") {
              (function (el) {
                var radios = form_to_submit.elements[el.name];
                for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
                  addEvent(radios[i], "click", function () {
                    validate_field(el, true);
                  });
                }
              })(input);
            } else if (input.tagName == "SELECT") {
              addEvent(input, "change", function () {
                validate_field(this, true);
              });
            } else if (input.type == "textarea") {
              addEvent(input, "input", function () {
                validate_field(this, true);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
      remove_tooltips();
      for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var elem = allInputs[i];
        if (needs_validate(elem)) {
          if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "select") {
            elem.value = elem.value.trim();
          }
          validate_field(elem) ? true : (no_error = false);
        }
      }
      if (!no_error && e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      resize_tooltips();
      return no_error;
    };
    addEvent(window, "resize", resize_tooltips);
    addEvent(window, "scroll", resize_tooltips);
    window._old_serialize = null;
    if (typeof serialize !== "undefined")
      window._old_serialize = window.serialize;
    _load_script(
      "//d3rxaij56vjege.cloudfront.net/form-serialize/0.3/serialize.min.js",
      function () {
        window._form_serialize = window.serialize;
        if (window._old_serialize) window.serialize = window._old_serialize;
      }
    );
    var form_submit = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (validate_form()) {
        // use this trick to get the submit button & disable it using plain javascript
        document.querySelector("#_form_1_submit").disabled = true;
        var serialized = _form_serialize(
          document.getElementById("_form_1_")
        ).replace(/%0A/g, "\\n");
        var err = form_to_submit.querySelector("._form_error");
        err ? err.parentNode.removeChild(err) : false;
        _load_script(
          "https://bonniebrightdesigns.activehosted.com/proc.php?" +
            serialized +
            "&jsonp=true"
        );
      }
      return false;
    };
    addEvent(form_to_submit, "submit", form_submit);
  })();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&display=swap");
& {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }
  * {
    outline: 0;
  }
  GLOBAL-STYLE ._form_hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  GLOBAL-STYLE ._form_show {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  ._form-top {
    top: 0;
  }
  ._form-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  ._form-left {
    left: 0;
  }
  ._form-right {
    right: 0;
  }
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="date"],
  textarea {
    padding: 6px;
    height: auto;
    border: #979797 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #000000 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  textarea {
    resize: none;
  }
  .frm-1 {
    margin: 1rem !important;
  }
  ._submit {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #e9afa3 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding: 12px !important;
  }
  ._close-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/esfkyjh1u_forms-close-dark.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 14.2px 14.2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 11px;
    right: 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 16.2px;
    height: 16.2px;
  }
  ._close-icon:before {
    position: relative;
  }
  ._form-body {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  ._form-image-left {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
  }
  ._form-content-right {
    margin-left: 164px;
  }
  ._form-branding {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  ._form-branding ._logo {
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    background-image: url("https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/hh9ujqgv5_aclogo_li.png");
    background-size: 130px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .form-sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
  }
  ._form-label,
  ._form_element ._form-label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
  ._dark ._form-branding {
    color: #333;
  }
  ._dark ._form-branding ._logo {
    background-image: url("https://d226aj4ao1t61q.cloudfront.net/jftq2c8s_aclogo_dk.png");
  }
  ._form_element {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  ._form_element * {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  ._form_element._clear {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  ._form_element._clear:after {
    clear: left;
  }
  ._form_element input[type="text"],
  ._form_element input[type="date"],
  ._form_element select,
  ._form_element textarea:not(.g-recaptcha-response) {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
  }
  ._field-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }
  ._inline-style {
    float: left;
  }
  ._inline-style input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
  }
  ._inline-style:not(._clear) + ._inline-style:not(._clear) {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  ._form_element img._form-image {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  ._form_element ._form-fieldset {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.01em 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
  }

  ._clear-element {
    clear: left;
  }
  ._full_width {
    width: 100%;
  }
  ._form_full_field {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  input[type="text"]._has_error,
  textarea._has_error {
    border: #f37c7b 1px solid;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]._has_error {
    outline: #f37c7b 1px solid;
  }
  ._error {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 10000001;
  }
  ._error._above {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    bottom: 39px;
    right: 0;
  }
  ._error._below {
    padding-top: 4px;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
  ._error._above ._error-arrow {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #f37c7b;
  }
  ._error._below ._error-arrow {
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #f37c7b;
  }
  ._error-inner {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    background-color: #f37c7b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  ._error-inner._form_error {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  ._button-wrapper ._error-inner._form_error {
    position: static;
  }
  ._error-inner._no_arrow {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  ._error-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  ._error-html {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  GLOBAL-STYLE .pika-single {
    z-index: 10000001 !important;
  }
  input[type="text"].datetime_date {
    width: 69%;
    display: inline;
  }
  select.datetime_time {
    width: 29%;
    display: inline;
    height: 32px;
  }
  @media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 667px) {
    GLOBAL-STYLE ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    & {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    ._form-content {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    ._form-inner {
      display: block;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    ._form-title,
    ._inline-style {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    ._form-title {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    ._form_element {
      margin: 0 0 20px;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    ._form-element,
    ._inline-style,
    input[type="text"],
    label,
    p,
    textarea:not(.g-recaptcha-response) {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    ._row._checkbox-radio label {
      display: inline;
    }
    ._row,
    p,
    label {
      margin-bottom: 0.7em;
      width: 100%;
    }
    ._row input[type="checkbox"],
    ._row input[type="radio"] {
      margin: 0 !important;
      vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
    ._row input[type="checkbox"] + span label {
      display: inline;
    }
    ._row span label {
      margin: 0 !important;
      width: initial !important;
      vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
    ._form-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto !important;
    }
    input[type="text"] {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.3em;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    input[type="radio"],
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.3em;
      height: 1.3em;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin: 0 0.3em 0 0;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    button[type="submit"] {
    }
    ._inline-style {
      margin: 20px 0 0 !important;
    }
  }

  & {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    *zoom: 1;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: 2px solid ##f9d2cb !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    color: #787878 !important;
  }
  ._inline-form,
  ._inline-form ._form-content,
  ._inline-form input,
  ._inline-form ._submit {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif, "IBM Plex Sans", arial, sans-serif;
  }

  ._form-title {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  ._inline-style {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ._inline-style input[type="text"],
  ._inline-style input[type="date"] {
    padding: 10px 12px;
  }
  ._inline-style button._inline-style {
    position: relative;
    top: 27px;
  }
  ._inline-style p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ._inline-style ._button-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 27px 12.5px 0 20px;
  }
  ._form-thank-you {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  @media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 667px) {
    ._inline-form._inline-style ._inline-style._button-wrapper {
      margin-top: 20px !important;
      margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
  }
  #_form_1_ ._submit {
    width: 222px;
  }
  #_form_1_ ._x35027614 input {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 222px;
    border-color: #e9afa3;
  }
  #_form_1_ ._x49576109 input {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 222px;
    border-color: #e9afa3;
  }
  #_form_1_ ._x43479952 input {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 222px;
    border-color: #e9afa3;
  }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <form
    method="POST"
    action="https://bonniebrightdesigns.activehosted.com/proc.php"
    id="_form_1_"
    class="_form _form_1 _inline-form _inline-style _dark"
    novalidate=""
  >
    <input type="hidden" name="u" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="f" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="sub" />
    <input type="hidden" name="v" value="2" />
    <div
      class="_form-content"
      style="
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: center;
      "
    >
      <div class="_form_element _x35027614 _inline-style frm-1">
        <label for="firstname" class="_form-label">
          Firstname
        </label>
        <div class="_field-wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstname"
            name="firstname"
            placeholder="First Name"
            required=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_form_element _x49576109 _inline-style frm-1">
        <label for="lastname" class="_form-label">
          LastName
        </label>
        <div class="_field-wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="lastname"
            name="lastname"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_form_element _x43479952 _inline-style frm-1">
        <label for="email" class="_form-label">
          Email
        </label>
        <div class="_field-wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            required=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_button-wrapper _inline-style frm-1">
        <button id="_form_1_submit" class="_submit" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="_clear-element"></div>
    </div>
<div class="_form-thank-you" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="_form-branding">
<div class="_marketing-by">Marketing by</div>
<a href="https://www.activecampaign.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=acforms" class="_logo">
<span class="form-sr-only">
ActiveCampaign
</span>
 </a>
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-kalam-qtut4?file=/index.html